# Avoiding modulo bias

Tags: c++, modulo

I've been looking around for how to overcome modulo bias, and a lot of the answers I'm seeing say you can avoid modulo bias by continuing to generate random numbers until you get one within the desired range. My problem isn't how to implement this or anything, but the theory behind it.

If you're forcing your generator to keep going until you get numbers from certain parts of your range, isn't that giving up a portion of randomness in itself? Because a true RNG wouldn't be 'guaranteed' to generate any specific sub-ranges within a range.

Is this just the best we can do, short of giving up a lot of performance, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why are you "giving up a lot of performance"? Either your range is small, so the remainder that you discard is tiny compared to the output range of the RNG, or your range is large, and so most of the RNG's results already fall within the range.

Comment: Your final sentence insinuates exclusives, when in reality this is both the best we can do *and* you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: @KerrekSB I mean if we're forcing it to represent the parts of the range that aren't biased every time we run the generator, it's not exactly random is it? I was asking if this is simply our best-case scenario short of coding something more truly random which (I assume) would cost in performance.

Comment: It may be confusing to say "random", which is vague. The goal here is to sample *uniformly* at random from the range `[a, b)`, when all you have is a source of *uniform* random numbers in some other range `[x, y)`. Everything is random in some way, but the goal is to make every number in the desired range *equally* likely.

Comment: @KerrekSB That makes a little more sense. I appreciate the explanation, thanks!